# jest.fn() v/s jest.mock()?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

For mocking uuidv4, I am using this :

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
jest.mock("uuid");
uuidv4.mockReturnValue("uuid123");
```

And for mocking window.confirm, I am using this:

```
window.confirm = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => true);
```

These both are working all right.
But when i try doing this i.e

```
const uuidv4 = jest.fn.mockImplementation(() => "uuid123");
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: jest.fn.mockImplementation is not a function
```

I am confused between jest.fn() and jest.mock().

Can someone please elaborate on which one to use and when to use, with suitable example?

Comment: In your second jest.fn you aren't *calling* it. And one you've succeeded you're left with the problem of how your mock function named uuidv4 actuality gets used by the code you're testing; that's what jest.mock helps with.

Comment: I am calling it inside the test, const id = uuidv4(); That is when I get this error.

Comment: @kob003 jest.fn.mockImplementation() and jest.fn().mockImplementation() aren't the same thing. The former is incorrect, the latter is. . Wherever you're calling uuidv4() is a different story because you won't reach this point if you don't use API correctly. Check the docs, it contains necessary examples to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick explanation for you:

- `jest.mock` is to mock a certain module. Once you write `jest.mock('uuid')` then it means all exported things would be turned to a `jest.Mock` type, that's why you can mock `v4` method: `v4.mockReturnValue('yourV4Id')`;

```js
jest.mock('aModule');

import {aMember} from "aModule";

// is now a jest mock type <=> jest.fn()
aMember.mockReturnValue('a value');
```

- `jest.fn` is a function which returns a `jest.Mock` type which can be considered as an function to create whatever you want:

```js
const aMock = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(1) // <=> const aMock = () => 1;

// The difference is jest mock type can be used to assert then. Most of cases is to check
// whether it gets called or not
```